# Saving results from a for loop as a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

This question is rather simple however looking at past questions on here has not yielded an answer that R accepts, sadly.

I am trying to run a For loop for a function and then encase the result within a matrix. The function that it is looping is:

```
knn <- function(X, t, k)
```

I am comfortable that the following loop generates the particular result that I would like into a matrix:

`for (i in 1:38){
  print(knn(IrisTrain_woclass, IrisTest_woclass[i, ], 3))
 }`

So to put it into a function I have tried to use:

```
my_vector <- vector("numeric", 10L)
for (i in 1:38){
 my_vector(i) <- knn(IrisTrain_woclass, IrisTest_woclass[i, ], 1)
 my_vector
}
```

however this comes up with

> could not find function "my_vector<-"

Comment: That is because you wrote `my_vector(i)` which looks like a function call.  I think that you meant  `my_vector[i]`.

Comment: Thanks for this! It works fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you try to subset a vector by using parentheses. If you use parentheses, R thinks you are trying to run a function. You can subset a vector by using brackets.
So, instead of `my_vector(i)` it should be `my_vector[i]` in the for-loop.